# Usage of まで in this Verb (Plain) + まで form+ Verb (Present/Future or Past)

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

I am uncertain about the usage of まで in case of punctual/static verbs in this Verb (Plain) + まで + Verb (present/future or past) form. Which means, do something till something.

> Present/Future Tense

In case of durative verb, using the Present/Future form makes sense

E.g. 私は行くまで食べ物を食べます
Meaning I will eat until I go

However, when I use punctual/stative verb it does not make any sense, as the function of  まで implies doing something until xyz happens. Now, since punctual verb are completed when performed once. So the following sentence, as per me, does not make any sense.

私は行くまで明かりをつけます

(Roughly it can mean, till I go, I will turn on the light)

- Inference 1: Further, as per my little understanding, since まで is used I tend to think that he will perform tha action of turning on the light again and again until he goes, which I do not want to convey.

What I want to convey is that I will turn on the lights (and keep them in that condition) until I go.

> Past Tense

Similar problem applies in this case as well. In case of Durative verb, using past form will work as well.

E.g. 私は行くまで食べ物を食べました.
Meaning I ate until I went.

However, when I use Punctual verb again with まで

E.g. 私は行くまで明かりをつけました。

- Inference 2: The same inference, as per my understanding,  that i was turning the lights on again and again comes into picture due to the nature of particle まで, which i do not want to convey.

As I wanted to convey was that until I went (left) I turned on the light (and it was in that state until I went)

> Usage of ていた instead of た

I think the past tense problems is solved by using ていた (past perfect) e.g. 私は行くまで明かりをつけていた. Meaning I had turned on the lights till I left. However, I am not sure about that.

1. Question 1: Is my 1st Inference/understanding correct i.e. 私は行くまで明かりをつけます (does not make any sense). If yes, can you give me an alternative, as I wanted to convey that, What I want to convey is that I will turn on the lights (and keep them in that condition) until I go.
2. Question 2: Is my 2nd inference/understanding correct i.e. 私は行くまで明かりをつけました (does not mean any sense). If yes can you give me an alternative as what i wanted to convey was Until I went I turned on the lights (and they were on till I left).
3. Question 3: Can ていた replace た in Verb(plain) + まで + Verb(Past)

ありがとう

教えてください

Comment: So in summary it sounds like you want to know how to say 'keep' e.g. "I will keep the lights on until I leave". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, however that is just one part of this question. The main part was that i wanted to know whether ます and ました will make sense in punctual verbs or not as per the context of the question

Comment: My gut feeling is, no it doesn't make sense. It sounds weird to me, but I'm not confident enough to say for certain. It sounds like a use for that dreaded noun (particle?) まま.

Comment: @user3856370 I think you're onto something, まま as well as the ておく construction come to mind at least for the part that you've addressed in your first comment

Comment: @APK I'm not sure if *eat* in this case can be considered a durative verb given that you have to have stopped eating before you could go, a better example might be「成功{せいこう}するまで続{つづ}ける」which means "I will keep going until I succeed."

Comment: @JansthcirlU Thanks for commenting, I am thinking that you might be looking at it from the end point perspective, i.e. from the point of time, the task completed to the stage at which is eating/will eat, which I do not believe applies in case of まで, as it means, doing xyz till  a certain point, which show cases that till that time I will continue to do this. What you are saying would apply to までに/前に.

Comment: @APK then I have no clue what you're trying to ask, please rewrite your question more clearly using English example sentences that you'd like to see translated. Refer to [this explanation](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7-made-meaning/) in case you need more general information about the usage of まで.